# Why is this UIViewController not updating after a call to twitter?

Tags: ios, twitter

I'm trying to build a basic twitter client as an exercise in learning iOS development. So far I have a TabBarController, where one tab is the user's timeline (which is working fine), and this new tab for the user's profile.  Most of the structure below of the twitter call was from an online tutorial to get the user's timeline, using XCode 5 and the twitter API 1.1. I then modified it to get the user's profile in this 2nd ViewController. In this profile view I have a UIImageView for the user's profile image, and a label for the # of followers.

When I first tap this tab for the profile view, the imageView is blank. When I click the other tab and then this profile tab a 2nd time, then the profile image is loaded. The followers label is never updated, but when I debug it, I can see that I'm getting the numFollowers value correctly.

So why is the profileImageView not updated on the initial view of the view, and why is the numFollowers label never updated?

Relevant bits of ViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self twitterProfile];
}

-(void) twitterProfile {
    ACAccountStore *account = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

    // Asks for the Twitter accounts configured on the device

    ACAccountType *accountType = [account accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

    [account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
     {
         // if we have access to the Twitter accounts configured on the device we will contact the Twitter API

         if (granted) {
             // Retrieve array of twitter accounts on device
             NSArray *arrayOfAccounts = [account accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
             // if there is at least one account we will contact the Twitter API
             if ([arrayOfAccounts count] > 0) {
                 ACAccount *twitterAccount = [arrayOfAccounts lastObject];
                 NSString *username = twitterAccount.username;
                 // API call that returns a user's profile
                 NSURL *requestAPI = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json" ];
                 // this is where we are getting the data using SLRequest
                 SLRequest *profile = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:requestAPI parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", username], @"screen_name", @"-1", @"cursor", nil]];
                 profile.account = twitterAccount;
                 // the postRequest: method call now accesses the NSData object returned
                 [profile performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *response, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {

                     NSDictionary *profileData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response
                                                                  options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                    error:&error];
                     if (profileData.count > 0) {
                         NSString *profileImageURL = [profileData objectForKey:@"profile_image_url"];
                         NSURL *imageUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:profileImageURL];
                         UIImage *profileImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl]];
                         _profileImageView.image = profileImage;
                         NSString *numFollowers = [profileData objectForKey:@"followers_count"];
                         _numFollowers.text = numFollowers;
                     }
                 }];
             }
         } else {
             // Handle failure to get account access
             NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
         }
     }];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should perform the updates in the foreground using the below code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSString *profileImageURL = [profileData objectForKey:@"profile_image_url"];
    NSURL *imageUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:profileImageURL];
    UIImage *profileImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl]];
    _profileImageView.image = profileImage;
    NSString *numFollowers = [profileData objectForKey:@"followers_count"];
    _numFollowers.text = numFollowers;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it; That dispatch_async was in the original handling of the twitter call and I had removed it when I copied and modified it for this call